# Does Japanese have as many English-derived words as English has French-derived words?

Tags: english, french, japanese, vocabulary

According to current corpora and other tools used by language researchers, does the current vocabulary of Japanese already contain as many words borrowed/derived from English as the number of English words derived from French?

Comment: I assume you mean modern French loan-words, like *déja-vu* or *roux*? Nearly a third of all English words are French loan words (at least according to Wikipedia, but the fraction is big whatever it is).

Comment: I would be amazed if this were the case: English has been absorbing French words for nearly a thousand years, Japanese has been accommodating English for only 150. I don't know the answer for sure, though.

Comment: Well, virtually *every* English word can be borrowed into Japanese.

Comment: As a starting point:  "*The study ‘Nihon no Sankotosho’ (Reference Books on Japan’), published by Nihon Toshokan Ky6kai (Japan Association of Libraries) in 1980, showed that **over half the 25,000 loanwords** in* Kadokawa’s Loanword Dictionary *entered the language after World War Two, **most of them from English. Since 1945**, aided by an expanding mass media,* ***thousands of English loanwords have been absorbed into Japanese.***" https://www.csun.edu/~bashforth/301_PDF/301_P_P/EnglishLoanWordsJapanese.pdf

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gairaigo_and_wasei-eigo_terms 
 http://www.macmillandictionaries.com/MED-Magazine/April2003/06-language-interference-loan-words.htm Tuttle New Dictionary of Loanwords in Japanese, Taeko Kamiya, Charles E. Tuttle Publishing Ltd., 1994; Easy Katakana, Tina Wells, McGraw-Hill, 1989 (The book covers 1,500 loan words from English)